# What does main-safe in Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning Coroutines of Kotlin. The Text A is from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/#8

What does main-safe in Kotlin Coroutines?

Does it mean the system will run them in background thread automatically when it need ?

Does it mean I will never use the code such as `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`  in both Room and Retrofit operation ?

**Text A**

*Both Room and Retrofit make suspending functions main-safe.
It's safe to call these suspend funs from Dispatchers.Main, even though they fetch from the network and write to the database.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does main-safe [mean for] Kotlin Coroutines?

You literally quote the answer yourself:

> It's safe to call these suspend funs from Dispatchers.Main, even though they fetch from the network and write to the database.

And the answer to

> Does it mean I will never use the code such as withContext(Dispatchers.IO) in both Room and Retrofit operation ?

is: Correct (assuming you configure them properly, e.g. use `suspend` modifier in Retrofit fun definitions).

Comment: But that's confusing. Then "suspend" doesn't guarrantee main-safety. Only the method's implementation does. ????

Comment: @JuanJoséMeleroGómez Correct, "suspend" by itself does not guarantee main-safety. A suspend fun can still block the UI thread if it is badly written. Roman talks about this explicitly here for example: https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761

Answer (score 12):

For me as an android developer this simple definition made perfect sens

> We consider a function main-safe when it doesn't block UI updates on
> the main thread.

Found it here https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines

Answer (score 3):

Please check this answer for the exact reason why the API calls works with retrofit without changing the dispatcher to IO, referencing https://stackoverflow.com/a/61216333/4354001  :

> It works because Retrofit's suspend implementation delegates to
> Call.enqueue. This means it already executes on its own background
> executor by default instead of using the caller's Dispatcher.