# Retrofit call in Kotlin Coroutines viewModelScope

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

Recently I've updated my `ViewModel` to use new `viewModelScope`. From its implementation, I see that `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` is set as the default `CoroutineDispatcher` for `viewModelScope`.

So when printing the current `Thread` in `viewModelScope.launch` it gives **Thread[main,5,main]**

But even though this runs in Main Thread, the following code works for me which performs a network call.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    userRepo.login(email, password)
}
```

Here `userRepo.login(email, password)` is `suspend` function, which calls `Retrofit` `suspend` function.

So how this works, if my Current Thread is Main Thread?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It works because Retrofit's `suspend` implementation delegates to `Call<T>.enqueue`. This means it already executes on its own background executor by default instead of using the caller's `Dispatcher`.

Comment: What if I'm calling this suspend function in  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) block? Does it still run in Call<T>.enqueue? If yes then the thread which is created using Dispatchers.IO is useless? Also is there any way I can debug or check the implementation of Retrofit ? If retrofit is anyway calling enqueue then is it lightweight thread as Dispatchers.IO

Comment: Yes, it still runs on Okhttp's dispatcher. No, the thread that is created isnt useless since normal coroutine optimizations apply. Look into the `HttpServiceMethod` class for debugging. And the dispatcher used depends on the configuration of the `OkHttpClient` provided to Retrofit.

Answer (score 2):

suspend functions are always safe to call from the main thread.  But if you are going to do heavy operations like fetch data from server, database, content loader... it is better to use the appropriate dispatcher, for example, Dispatcher.IO.

If you want you can use this dispatcher with the viewmodelScope, and then all the suspends functions runs with this dispatcher.

Now the ViewModel is an Executor (a class that changes the execute from Main to background)

If you are going to change the dispatcher in the ViewModel, a good practice is to inject this Dispatcher by constructor to test the ViewModel.

Comment: But literally @Kiskae said that it is not necessary operation while u are using suspend function with room or retrofit. But you are talking about the situation when you do not use these libraries?

Comment: with room or retrofit is not necessary because under the hood, I think retrofit is using the io dispatcher, and probably the room library too